# Does PDF.js extract any page styling information?

Tags: parsing, pdf, pdf.js

I'm in a situation where I need to distinguish whether or not a PDF has a certain layout after scanning the document for text.  Is this possible with PDF.js and if so where would I find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PDFs consist of very low-level drawing commands, and as such it is *very* difficult to extract any formatting information from them, no matter what tool/library. (See for example, [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-28640-0_20))

Comment: Thanks - thats what I figured but having little to no actual knowledge under the hood I figured I'd ask the internets